# Travis CI using the wrong version of Java

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, travis-ci

I've been trying to set up a Maven Project (Spring Boot) and connect it to Travis CI for the past 12 hours and it keeps failing. It's driving me crazy. It looks like the virtual environment on Travis CI website is using the wrong version of Java as seen **here**

[image: here]

and

**here** [image: here]

Here are a few more screenshots that might helpful:

My .bash_profile and JAVA_HOME are correctly set

[image: JAVA_HOME]

[image: bash_profile]

and finally my .travis.yml inside my spring boot project

[image: travis]

I created my Spring Boot project using this site: https://start.spring.io/
I didn't change anything expect the java version, I set it to 13

Here's what my pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>13</source> <!-- 1.8,1.9,1.10,11,12,13 -->
                    <target>13</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: TravisCI needs to know which java version to use, you need to specify that in your travis file, else it will use the default. Also local settings have zero effect on what runs on travis obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the jdk version that you want to use in your Travis CI configuration file:

```
language: java

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
  - openjdk8
```

More information about setting up java projects in Travis CI [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/).

Comment: This solution worked. Just had to use oraclejdk13 or openjdk13